# "user-scalable=no" not working with webkit-column-count & width

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm working on an HTML content that is going to be opened in android webview.
I want to make the HTML content to be in columns (to make it looks like a book), and at the same time, I want to disable double tap zoom feature. so I use this code in the  section of the HTML file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
```

and I use javascript code to format the  style:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.width =500;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitColumnCount = 2;
```

I found out that if I use these codes together, `user-scalable=no` is not working, the user can double tap to zoom.

may I know if these 2 codes are conflicting with each other, or got other problem?
if they are not working together, is there any other way to disable double tap zoom?

Thank you.

Comment: What you mean by `getElementsByTagName('body')[0]`

Comment: im selecting the first element with tag name 'body'